# What am I doing wrong with this AFNetworking JSON Post?

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

I have an odd problem... I'm doing this ios http/json post using AFNetworking against a rails server and the expected output is something like:

```
{"success":true,"auth_token":"4D8CyUsyGZdqo6X1TCeq"}
```

Sometimes it works as expected, but often on the rails side the request is not detected as a "JSON" request so it serves up HTML.  Anyone have an idea on this?  Is there something I'm doing wrong with regards to setting up the JSON request?

```
 NSDictionary *parameter = @{@"email":@"philswenson@mymail.com", @"password":@"mypassword"};
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000"]];
    [httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
    [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

    [httpClient postPath:@"api/v1/sessions" parameters:parameter success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"Here is what we got %@", jsonString);
        NSDictionary *loginResult = [jsonString objectFromJSONString];
        NSNumber* success = [loginResult objectForKey:@"success"];
        NSLog(@"success = %@", success);
        NSLog(@"yay");
        // sample output:
        //  {"success":true,"auth_token":"4D8CyUsyGZdqo6X1TCeq"}

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        [self handleConnectionError:error];
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

I know with my service, I need to add  application/jsonrequest for accept to my parameters like this:

```
NSDictionary *parameter = @{@"email":@"philswenson@mymail.com", @"password":@"mypassword", @"accept:application/jsonrequest"};
```

The AFJSONParameterEncoding only tells it to send the parameters in a JSON file.  I need to send a parameter to tell it how to send the data back.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

`[httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the suggestions - no dice....  the setDefaultHeader actually caused a crash (whatever the iOS term is for access violation)...

The "accept:application/jsonrequest"} didn't see any difference...

I ended up using this code:

```
    NSDictionary *parameter = @{@"email" : @"phil@gmail.com", @"password" : @"mypw", @"format":@"json"};
```